Are assignments from .Net methods atomic when stopping PowerShell?
Consider the following code which opens a file for writing in a job, stops that job, then opens the same file for writing again:
$filePath = [system.io.path]::GetTempFileName()
$job =
    Start-ThreadJob             `
        -ArgumentList $filePath `
        -ScriptBlock {
            param($filePath)
            end {
                $fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)
            }
            clean {
                ${fs}?.Dispose()
            }
        }

$job | Stop-Job
$fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)

The clean{} block seems to run to completion before Stop-Job completes, which means $fs gets disposed if it was assigned.
But what happens if the job is stopped when new() has already started, but the assignment to $fs has not completed?  Does the assignment complete?  Is the following line atomic when stopping PowerShell?
$fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)


Background
Working definition of atomicity
For this question I think the following definition of "atomic" applies:

Given a statement running in a runspace
a. that includes an expression that produces a new object from a .Net method referred to in that expression,
b. that mentions a PowerShell variable accessible at the scope of the statement,
c. where the statement is an assigment of the object returned by the .Net method in (a) to the PowerShell variable in (b), and
d. where the statement and assignment would succeed without error or exception if the runspace were not stopped,
the statement is atomic iff for all possible combinations of
e. instants in time stopping of the runspace is invoked, and 
f. valid implementations of the .Net method as defined by applicable C# or .Net standards and specifications
either
g. the .Net method does not begin executing, or
h. the entire .Net method executes to completion and the object it returns is assigned to the variable.

@mklement0 alluded to this definition in a manner that might improve clarity:

...assuming that the RHS has run to completion and can be assigned to the target variable without violating a type constraint, is there a way for Stop-Job to get in the way of the assignment?

Assignment Expressions that aren't Atomic
It's rather trivial to construct an assignment statement where construction occurs but assignment does not complete.  The (somewhat absurd-looking) statement
$fs =
    @([System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)
      Start-Sleep 1)

is one such example.  In that case the job can be stopped without the first StreamWriter getting disposed, and then the second new() fails with the error
Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzc3tf0.tmp' because it is being used by another process."

But that conspicuous Start-Sleep could be replaced with any manner of legitimate utilitarian work.  Another scenario that seems vulnerable to this problem is the case where the constructor is wrapped in an advanced function like New-StreamWriter.  Does the introduction of the advanced function prevent assignment from the .Net method it invokes being atomic?
Test Results
I prepared a test below that tests different expressions and reports when it detects that the assignment wasn't atomic.  But that test can pass with fortunate timing even though the assignment under test isn't, fact, atomic.  So it can't prove that there is no problem, only that there is a problem.
The test output the following:
result assignment                                         use_again_error
------ ----------                                         ---------------
-      $fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)
        $c.Set()
-      $fs = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $filePath
        $c.Set()
❌      $fs =                                              Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The
           @([System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)     process cannot access the file
             $c.Set()                                     'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpgm0d0q.tmp' because
             Start-Sleep 1)                               it is being used by another process."
-      $fs = New-StreamWriter $filePath

Test Code
{$fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)
 $c.Set()                                         } ,
{$fs = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $filePath
 $c.Set()                                         } ,
{$fs =
    @([System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)
      $c.Set()
      Start-Sleep 1)                              } ,
{$fs = New-StreamWriter $filePath} |
ForEach-Object {
    $assignment = $_
    $filePath = [system.io.path]::GetTempFileName()
    $c = [System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim]::new() # indicates constructor has completed
    $job =
        Start-ThreadJob `
            -ArgumentList $filePath,$assignment,$c `
            -ScriptBlock {
                param($filePath,$assignment,$c)
                begin {
                    function New-StreamWriter {
                        param($filePath)
                        [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)
                        $c.Set()
                    }
                }
                end {
                    . ($assignment.Ast.GetScriptBlock())
                }
                clean {
                    ${fs}?.Dispose()
                }
            }
    $c.Wait() | Out-Null
    $assignment_error =
        @(
            $job.Error
            try {
                $job | Receive-Job -ea Stop
            }
            catch {
                $_
            }
        ) |
            Select-Object -Unique

    $use_again_error  = $(try { $fs2 = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)} catch {$_})
    [pscustomobject]@{
        result           = $(if($assignment_error) {'⚠️'} else {if($use_again_error) {'❌'} else {''}})
        assignment       = $assignment
        assignment_error = $assignment_error
        use_again_error  = $use_again_error
    }
    ${fs2}?.Dispose()
} |
Format-Table `
    -Wrap `
    -Property @(
        @{ Name = 'result';Expression = 'result'; Width = 'result'.Length }
        @{ Name = 'assignment';Expression = 'assignment'; Width = 50 }
        @{ Name = 'use_again_error';Expression = 'use_again_error'; Width = 60 }
    )
``


$fs = @([System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath); Start-Sleep 1) is a completely unfair test. Start-Sleep allows interrupts and a ctor that gets a handle unless it had a CreateAsync would never allow such thing.

I agree.  That's the very point of the question.  In principle, a .Net method could do something similar to that unfair test.  But it's not clear whether the assignment would complete if the asynchronous or long-running thing happens in a .Net method.

"A .Net method could do something similar to that unfair test." not really unless it was designed by a careless developer.

"...not really unless it was designed by a careless developer." Why couldn't the constructor thread be preempted during construction and the job be stopped before the constructor resumes?

A ctor wouldn't allow interrupts and a CreateAsync method would allow interruption via a CancellationToken at which point it's the responsibility of the developer of that type to properly dispose handles if the method was interrupted

"A ctor wouldn't allow interrupts..." Do you have a reference for this?  I haven't seen this restriction documented anywhere.

You can google it... a ctor must guarantee an object is instantiated or an exception is thrown.

"...a ctor must guarantee an object is instantiated or an exception is thrown."  That much is clear.  But the question of preemption is the issue here.

A ctor is invoked or not invoked, if invoked the object is created or an exception is thrown. If not invoked no handle is acquired thus nothing gets disposed. Not sure how else to explain it, my prev. comment should've been clear.

Please include your definition of atomicity in the question.

@MathiasR.Jessen I attempted a working definition of "atomic" for this question and added it here.

TL;DR

Is the following line atomic when stopping PowerShell?
$fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)


All of the tests I have seen suggest that the answer is "yes".  It is worth nothing, however, that the following assignments are not atomic when stopping PowerShell:
$fs = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $filePath
$fs = Set-Variable fs ([System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath))


Are assignments from .Net methods atomic when stopping PowerShell?

The most accurate answer I have found to this question is something like the following: It depends on whether any of the operations involved check the Stopping flag.
The most practical answer I can offer is the following: If whether an assignment is atomic matters for your code, test the formulation of the assignment statement in question using something like the test code from mklement0's answer or this answer.

Empirical Test
The question boils down to

$fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)

...
...what happens if the job is stopped when new() has already started, but the assignment to $fs has not completed? Does the assignment complete?

In order to test what happens in that condition we need to contrive the following:

a PowerShell job that progresses until part-way through a constructor invocation, then waits for that job to be stopping before continuing
a script to create that job, and some way of stopping that job once it's in that constructor

With such a setup, it's simply a matter of checking from the clean{} block whether the variable to which the constructed object was assigned is null.
I implemented such a test which can be found in this gist.  That test output the following:
atomic scriptblock
------ -----------
  True { $a = [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs) }
  True { $a = ([AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)) }
  True { $a = $([AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)) }
  True { $a = @([AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)) }
  True { $a = ($x =[AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)) }
  True { $a = $(($x =[AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs))) }
  True { $a = @(($x =[AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs))) }
  True { $a = [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs),
                 [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs) }
  True { $a = @([AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)
                   [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)) }
 False { Set-Variable a ([AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)) }
 False { $a = New-Object AtomicAssignmentSourceMock $mockArgs }
 False { $a = . {[AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)} }
 False { $a = & {[AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)} }

Analysis
I think the above results can be summarized as follows:



Assigment Statement Involves
Atomic




PowerShell command
no


calling PowerShell scriptblock
no


no PowerShell commands or scriptblock
yes



But there are also some peculiarities that suggest this might not generalize as simply as the above table suggests.  For example, using the same setup, I tested the following indirect assignments from [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs) to $a:
$x = [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)
[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(100)
$a = $x

and
$x = [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)
Out-Null
$a = $x

Those two assignments are atomic.  Whereas,
$x = [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
$a = $x

and
$x = [AtomicAssignmentSourceMock]::new($mockArgs)
Write-Verbose 'something'
$a = $x

are not atomic.
I suspect this is a result of what Bruce Payette described as follows:

Stop() is implemented by having the runtime check the Stopping flag in a bunch of places. Any long-running operation should check but we don't check for every operation as that would be too much overhead. I don't believe we check it for assignment statements (but I'd have to check the code).

In other words, whether a series of operations is atomic seems to depend on whether those (or, perhaps, the degree to which) those operations yield to the "stopping" signal.
Solutions
Proposed Language Enhancement
PowerShell currently seems to makes no guarantees about whether an assignment is atomic.  Bruce Payette's comment above suggests to me the atomicity observed may well be a side-effect of performance considerations as opposed to intended behavior.  I created this proposal to extend PowerShell to provide at least one built-in atomic way to construct and assign an object to a variable.  That seems like something that ought to exist, but there are lots of factors that can prevent a proposal like that from coming to fruition.
Atomic Construction/Assignment Binary Cmdlet
The most compelling solution that emerged after further experimenting is a binary Cmdlet that combines New-Object and Set-Variable.  A proof-of-concept of such a command is here.  Rewriting the assignment
$fs = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($filePath)

with that Cmdlet, the assignment becomes
Set-CleanupVariable fs System.IO.StreamWriter $filePath

I think the advantages of this approach over some other possibilities can be summarized as follows:

The mechanics of the assignment is atomic by design, rather than what appears to be incidental.
Call sites using this command are easily and unambiguously recognizable as atomic  to a reader acquainted with the command.
The atomicity of assignments is not vulnerable to changes to checks for Stopping in the PowerShell engine or other commands.
The same technique should work to achieve atomicity for a Use-Object implementation.  So the call sites of both would look familiar to anyone acquainted with either.
The same technique works with both PowerShell 7 and Windows PowerShell.


To provide some background information about PowerShell assignments:

Assignment (which may involve implicit variable creation) isn't attempted until the RHS expression or command has run to completion:

E.g., try { $foo = '/', 'nosuch' | Get-Item -ErrorAction Stop } catch { } doesn't create variable $foo (if it existed before, its value remains untouched), even though one System.IO.DirectoryInfo did get constructed before the error occurred.

Notably, this means that the RHS execution may construct objects that aren't captured in a variable, preventing their timely release via .Dispose() if they are instances of .NET types that control unmanaged resources and therefore implement the IDisposable interface, such as the [System.IO.StreamWriter] type referenced in your question.


Important:

The above provokes a (script-)terminating error, by way of setting the common -ErrorAction parameter to Stop, which is what prevents the assignment.

The same applies to the other kind of terminating error: statement-terminating ones, as potentially (though rarely) emitted by cmdlets, expressions (e.g. 1 / 0), or as the result of exceptions thrown by .NET methods (e.g., [int]::Parse('notanumber'); see this answer for details about the two kinds of terminating errors.


Without -ErrorAction Stop, Get-Item would report a non-terminating error for the nosuch input path, which would not abort the assignment; the assignment would still succeed, and record the result of (just) Get-Item / in the variable, and would even technically succeed if none of the input paths exist.[1]





Even when the RHS runs to completion the assignment may fail due to a type mismatch owing to type constraints:

E.g., [int] $foo = 'notanumber' fails, and variable $foo, unless it already existed, isn't created.




It follows from the above:

You can not generally guarantee that objects constructed on the RHS also end up in the variable being assigned to.

As discussed in the comments, a .NET constructor call is in itself atomic: it either returns an instance of the requested type or it throws an exception.

Thus, in the context of a PowerShell assignment, a RHS comprising only a .NET constructor call via the intrinsic static ::new() method is de facto atomic, except if there's a failure due to a type constraint.

Notably, this means that using the Set-Variable cmdlet instead of the = operator and / or using the New-Object cmdlet instead of the static ::new() method is not atomic, as you've verified yourself:

Replacing $foo = [regex]::new($using:s) with either
$foo = New-Object regex $using:s or Set-Variable foo ([regex]::new($using:s)) makes the test code below fail.




The source code underlying the Stop-Job cmdlet is quite complex and the linked help topic provides no specific information, but on your feedback and the code below:

The atomicity of an assignment in the context of job code stopped via Stop-Job (as well as in the context of foreground code stopped with Ctrl+C) is de facto ensured as of PowerShell 7.5.x if and only if:

you use = (rather than Set-Variable)

and only if the RHS is a pure expression, meaning that it is composed
exclusively of operator expressions, with the exceptions noted below, and / or .NET method calls (including constructor calls via ::new()), though so-called language statements, e.g. if and foreach, may be used too, as long as they operate on pure expressions only.

Caveat: Since this behavior isn't documented, it is at least hypothetically subject to change; based on the quote in your own answer, it seems that it is a somewhat accidental fallout from the implementation not checking for the Stopping flag in pure expressions.



Conversely, if a pipeline is involved in the statement that happens to be executing at the time Stop-Job terminates the job, objects constructed in that pipeline are not assigned to the LHS variable (it is never created or updated); seemingly, a check for the Stopping flag is performed in this case, and the statement as a whole is aborted, with no assignment taking place.

Notably, any call to a cmdlet, function, script file, script block, or external program involves a pipeline, and so do &, the call operator, ., the dot-sourcing operator, $(...), the subexpression operator and @(...), the array-subexpression operator, but not (...), the grouping operator.






The following test code (note that a t.log file is temporarily created in the current directory):

involves a type constraint-free variable assignment from a .NET constructor call that takes several seconds to complete, in the context of a thread job.

tries to stop the thread job before the assignment has a chance to complete, to see if it completes nonetheless, i.e. to see if the effect of Stop-Job is deferred until after the assignment completes.


# Create a large string.
$s = 'x' * 512mb

$j = Start-ThreadJob {
  begin {
    if (Test-Path t.log) { Remove-Item -ErrorAction Stop t.log }
  }
  process {
    'Processing...' | Set-Content t.log
    # Call a constructor with ::new() and assign the instance
    # returned with `=`:
    # Note: This particular constructor call takes 
    #       on the order of *several seconds* to return.
    $foo = [regex]::new($using:s)
  }
  clean {
    # On cleanup, log whether variable $foo was created and
    # what its type is, if any.
    "Does `$foo exist? $([bool] (Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore foo))`nType of the value stored in `$foo: [$($foo.GetType())]" |
      Add-Content t.log
  }
}

# Sleep a little to give the job a chance to start - but not to finish.
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200

# Stop and remove the job.
$j | Stop-Job
$j | Remove-Job


# Print the contents of the log.
Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore t.log
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore t.log # clean up.

In my tests, running 100 iterations of the above, they consistently output the following, suggesting that, indeed, the assignment did reliably complete before the job was stopped:
Processing...
Does $foo exist? True
Type of the value stored in $foo: [regex]


[1] In that case, $foo would store [System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value aka the enumerable null, which is PowerShell's way of representing the absence of output from a command. In expression contexts, this value behaves the same as $null. See this answer for details.

"...I assume that a Stop-Job call can not interrupt a runspace between the act of having captured a run-to-completion RHS and assigning the result to a PowerShell variable..." I was hoping this too, but this testing seems to show there are many ways to express a construction/assignment statement where construction succeeds but assignment does not complete.

@alx9r, as this answer states, there are indeed many ways in which instances constructed on the RHS of an assignment may not end up in the target variable - just by the logic of assignments themselves, irrespective of whether or not Stop-Job is used. The focus of my statement is: assuming that the RHS has run to completion and can be assigned to the target variable without violating a type constraint, is there a way for Stop-Job to get in the way of the assignment? I'm hesitant to dig into all of your repro code, given that I don't see a Stop-Job call in it.

"The focus of my statement is: assuming that the RHS has run to completion and can be assigned to the target variable without violating a type constraint, is there a way for Stop-Job to get in the way of the assignment"  Yes.  That is exactly the topic of this question.

"I'm hesitant to dig into all of your repro code, given that I don't see a Stop-Job call in it" Ah, I see.  The call is instead to $job.StopJobAsync().  As far as I understand the stopping implementation, .StopJob(), .StopJobAsync(), Stop-Job, and CTRL+C all result in the same Stopping pipeline state.

Thank you for your much simpler demonstration code.  Replacing $foo = [regex]::new($using:s) with Set-Variable foo ([regex]::new($using:s)) or $foo = New-Object regex $using:s outputs Type of the value stored in $foo: [] which, I  think is an example of "Stop-Job getting in the way of the assignment".  That behavior matches the results from my test.

Thanks, @alx9r - I've updated the answer substantially. The bottom line seems to be: Only true assignments (using =) whose RHS are pure expressions are atomic with respect to stoppage by Stop-Job. By contrast, they are not if a pipeline is involved (any command call or $(...) or @(...))

Thank you.  Your answer looks accurate to me.  My only quibble is with the wording of "The atomicity of an assignment...is guaranteed...".  Consider this comment which suggests to me the atomicity we are observing may well be a side-effect of performance considerations as opposed to intended behavior.  The assignments you go on to describe indeed seem to be reliably atomic in this version of PowerShell.  However, I'm afraid that behavior is currently far from guaranteed.

Thanks, @alx9r; I was just catching up on your answer (+1), and I see what you're saying about the side effect; I'll revise the wording.

"Since this behavior isn't documented, it is at least hypothetically subject to change..." I created this proposal to address this.
